# Bootstrap3 のファントアイコンを増加したい

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

**Bootstrap3 アイコンを増やしたい**のですが、どうすれば良いでしょうか？

**Font Awesome**
・クラス指定ではなく、iタグで指定しなければいけないのでしょうか？
・既存の「Bootstrap3 アイコン」と併用可能でしょうか？

**Font Awesome 以外**
・「Bootstrap3 アイコン」として使用可能なフォントはあるでしょうか？

Comment: "(画像形式ではない)Bootstrap3 アイコンを増やしたいのですが、どうすれば良いでしょうか？”　とはどういうことでしょうか？

Comment: Bootstrap3 アイコンってフォントアイコン以外にありましたっけ？

Comment: (画像形式ではない)表記を削除しましたー

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> クラス指定ではなく、iタグで指定しなければいけないのでしょうか？

Font Awesome はインライン要素で利用することが想定されており、i 以外 (span など) を利用することもできます: [Font Awesome is designed to be used with inline elements (we like the <i> tag for brevity, but using a <span> is more semantically correct).](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/)

> 既存の「Bootstrap3 アイコン」と併用可能でしょうか？

Bootstrap のアイコンと併用可能です。